# Python while True has two variables in same line?

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, computer-vision, nested-loops

Example program,

1.

```
while True:
   sucess, image = cv2.imshow(img)
```

2. 

```
while True:
   _,frame = cv2.imread()
```

what does the syntax mean? what do they mean by assigning two variables for one value?
is sucess some inbuilt command?

Comment: it probably means that the method returns two values oh and the `_` tells python that that variable is not needed so it gets garbage collected or sth

Comment: It's called [tuple unpacking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/). It's the same as `name, age = 'Bob', 45`.

Comment: The unpacking is nothing to do with the `while True`.

Comment: `_` is a standard practice to indicate the variable is not used.

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b = c
```

That syntax means that `c` is expected to be a sequence of two values.  The first value is assigned to `a`, and the second value is assigned to `b`.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Answer (score 0):

This means `cv2.imread()` and `cv2.imshow()` return a tuple. There can be other way to get result.

```
result = cv2.imread()
succes = result[0]
image = result[1]
```